# How to kill nodejs child processes which execute python commands including activating and deactivating venv

Tags: python, node.js, express, virtualenv, child-process

I'm new to using child process module in nodejs, and got stuck while using python's virtualenv libs

I have a post route in an expressjs api, which is intended to activate a python virtualenv, run python on exec() child process and deactivate the virtualenv.

I have it setup like this in one of the modules in the project folder

```
// importing node modules
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const kill = require("tree-kill");
```

Within the controller function, I'm trying to create child processes this way

```
let activate_proc = exec("source pyenv/bin/activate");
let command_proc = exec("python insert.py arg1 arg2", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    // handle status/messages with http codes
});
let deactivate_proc = exec("deactivate");
```

I was able to capture the pids for these processes and tried to kill using the tree-kill by pausing for 10 seconds

```
setTimeout(() => {
    kill(command_proc.pid);
    kill(activate_proc.pid);
    kill(deactivate_proc.pid);
    console.log("Killed all processes");
}, 10000)
```

This seems to be working but somehow, if the command_proc takes more time, it might conflict.

Is there a more efficient way to kill them asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

you can run them synchronously instead, with [execSync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexecsynccommand-options)

try this:

```
// importing node modules
const {execSync } = require('child_process');


let activate_proc = execSync('source pyenv/bin/activate');
let command_proc;
let deactivate_proc;

// use try/catch for stderr
try {

    command_proc = execSync('python insert.py arg1 arg2');

    // stdout buffer, turn it to string
    const result = command_proc.toString();

    console.log('command_proc result: ', result);

    // handle status/messages with http codes
    // ... process command_proc

    // finish
    deactivate_proc = execSync('deactivate');
      
} catch (err) {
    // handle command_proc err
    console.log('output', err);
    console.log('sdterr', err.stderr.toString());
}
```